# Java Spring: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary ;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I have created a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo/" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
void addPhotoData(@RequestBody Photo photo, @RequestParam("data")
        MultipartFile photoData) {

    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = photoData.getInputStream();
        photoService.save(photo, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I send the request with Postman:[image]
[image]

I cannot understand why I receive the error 415 not supported.
Help!

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Type header in Postman ? If so, try removing it and resend the request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932391/9437031

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try wrapping the request body into an object.

```
 public class Payload {
   private String name;
   private String url;
   private MultipartFile data;
...
}
```

Add `consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }` and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo/" , method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public @ResponseBody void addPhotoData(@ModelAttribute Payload payload) {
...

}
```

There is also `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` constant instead of using that string

Comment: When i use `consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }` my routes stopped working .

Answer (score 2):

This is called multipart mixed type. Try changing your signature like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo/" , method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/mixed"})
public @ResponseBody void addPhotoData(@RequestPart Photo photo, @RequestPart("data")
        MultipartFile photoData) {
```

Comment: @pvpkiran is right I think.  This worked for me anyways.  Key points; 1) `consumes="multipart/mixed"`.  2) The Photo arg becomes a `@RequestPart`.  3) Lastly, at time of writing I don't think Postman supports sending `multipart/mixed` requests.  However, curl does so this curl command worked for me `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -F "photo={\"name\":\"test\"};type=application/json" -F "data=@/tmp/somefile" http://localhost:8080/photos`.  HTH