# multipart/form-data not not suported Springboot api

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm trying to make a POST request in my @PostMapping endpoint, but I'm receiving the following error(It was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working.):

`2023-07-11T02:22:25.976-03:00  WARN 8276 --- [-nio-443-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]`

Here is my code:

```java
    @PostMapping("/modificar-produto/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Object> modificarProduto(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid DadosAtualizacaoProduto dadosAtualizacao,
    @RequestParam boolean deletarImagem, @RequestParam int posicaoImagem) throws IOException{
        try{
            Produto produto = produtoRepository.findProdutoByid(id);
            String[] imagensUrls = produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl().split(",");
            if(dadosAtualizacao.nome() != null){
                produto.setNome(dadosAtualizacao.nome());
            }if(dadosAtualizacao.descricao() != null){
                produto.setDescricao(dadosAtualizacao.descricao());
            }if(dadosAtualizacao.preco() != null){
                produto.setPreco(dadosAtualizacao.preco());
            }if(dadosAtualizacao.imagem() !=null && !deletarImagem){
                var imagem = dadosAtualizacao.imagem();
                System.out.println("URLS INICIO:" + produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl());

                System.out.println(imagensUrls.length);

                if(imagensUrls.length != 6) {    
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Map<String, Object> uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(imagem.getBytes(), ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
                        var imagemUrl = uploadResult.get("secure_url");
                        produto.getImagens().setImagensUrl(produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl().concat("," + imagemUrl));
                    }else{
                        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("O máximo de imagens que um produto pode ter é 6");
                }

                    System.out.println("URLS FINAL:" + produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl());
                }

                if (deletarImagem) {
                    if (posicaoImagem >= 0 && posicaoImagem <= 6) {
                        System.out.println("URLS INICIO DELETE:" + produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl());

                        System.out.println("ENTROU NO BLOCO DE EXCLUIR A IMAGEM PELO INDICE");
                        var imagemExcluida = extractPublicId(imagensUrls[posicaoImagem]);
                        cloudinary.uploader().destroy(imagemExcluida, ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
                        System.out.println("url da  imagem sendo excluida"+ imagensUrls[posicaoImagem]);
                        imagensUrls = ArrayUtils.remove(imagensUrls, posicaoImagem);
                        String result = String.join(",", imagensUrls);
                        produto.getImagens().setImagensUrl(result);

                    } else {
                        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Índice de imagem inválido");
                    }

                    System.out.println("URLS FINAL DELETE:" + produto.getImagens().getImagensUrl());
                }
                produtoRepository.save(produto);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
            }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
            }
    }
```

I saw that someone has had this problem before, but the solution provided didn't work for me. The suggested solution was to change @RequestBody to @ModelAttribute, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874967/java-spring-content-type-multipart-form-databoundary-charset-utf-8-not-supp

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think it might be something related to Insomnia or Tomcat because it was working before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: if you import the @RequestBody from Spring Boot, it won't work, but if you import it from Swagger, it will work.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
```