# Spring boot (3.1.1) not uploading multipart form data - 400 bad request using @requestParams, 415 error using @requestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up an endpoint in Spring Boot(3.1.1) to upload images to storage. But I'm running into errors trying to hit that endpoint in Postman. I keep getting 400 or 415.

**Attempt 1**

When I send a request to this endpoint, I get a 500 bad request saying that it's looking for "file" in params. My form-data is stored in the request body so it makes sense that it wouldn't be there, but everything I've looked at is telling me to put the form-data in the body and use @RequestParam to get the file

```
@PostMapping(value = "/images", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity\<String\> uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");

}
```

```
 org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [72148a9b-1] Resolved [MissingRequestValueException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required query parameter 'file' is not present."] for HTTP POST /api/v1/images
```

**Attempt 2**

When I send a request to this endpoint using @RequestBody or @RequestPart, I get a 415 Unsupported Media type. The request that I make does have the Content-Type set to "multipart/form-data"

```
@PostMapping(value = "/images", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity\<String\> uploadFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");

}
```

```
org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [95cb569d-1] Resolved [UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException: 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------181292923510540258424514' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile"] for HTTP POST /api/v1/images
```

[Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVwCB.png)

Comment: Hello, this seems a duplicate of :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874967/java-spring-content-type-multipart-form-databoundary-charset-utf-8-not-supp

Can you try that please?

Comment: The problem is very similar. I will see if I can extract some syntax from it. Thanks.

Comment: @Evandro I was able to get past my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@PostMapping(path = "/images", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

```
    return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");
```

}